# if $(X,\tau)$ is an $T_1$- space, then every subset of $X$ is a saturated set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

In an general topology exercise I have to prove that if $(X,\tau)$ is an $T_1$- space, then every subset of $X$ is a saturated set (i.e. it is an intersection of open sets).

---

**My approach:**

Because $(X,\tau)$ is a $T_1$- space, then every singleton is closed.

Let $A \in \tau$, then we can write: $A=\bigcup \limits_{x\in A} \{x\}$. Therefore: $X \setminus A= X \setminus \bigcup \limits_{x\in A} \{x\}= \bigcap \limits_{x \in A} X\setminus \{x\}$.

If we define a set $P\in\tau, P:= X \setminus A$, then we end up with:

$$P=\bigcap \limits_{x\in X\setminus P} X\setminus\{x\}$$

And because because every singleton is closed, every $X\setminus\{x\}$ is opened, this $P$ is the intersection of open intervals.

---

After writing the proof I realized that I assumed that $\forall P \in \tau,\exists A \in \tau: P=X\setminus A$. Is this true in this specific case? If so how can I prove it?
In : $P=\bigcap \limits_{x\in X\setminus P} X\setminus\{x\}$, the intersection of those sets can either be finite or infinite. Is this a problem? Because for a set to be a topology it has to be closed under only a finite number of intersections. In the definition of a saturated set is it specified if the number of intersections is finite or if it can be an infinite number of intersections?

Comment: What is your definition of a saturated set? Moreover, if you want to show every set is saturated, then why do let $P \in \tau?$

Comment: In mathematics, in particular in topology, a subset of a topological space (X, τ) is saturated if it is an intersection of open subsets of X.

Comment: @Eduude: That is not a very common definition. I’ve been a topologist for decades, and this is the first time that I’ve encountered it at all. In my experience the most common use of the term in general topology is in connection with quotients and their associated partitions. It is definitely a usage that you should define in any question that you ask about it.

Comment: Are you talking about the $T_1$ - space definition? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Eduude: No, of course not; I’m talking about this odd use of the term *saturated*.

Comment: I'm still in the beginning of the topology book and I still don't know much about the subject, but they gave the following definition: A subset $S$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be saturated if it is an intersection of open sets in $(X,\tau)$ @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Eduude: And as I said, this is not common terminology. What is the book?

Comment: It's called "Topology Without Tears" @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Eduude: The online text by Morris? I can’t rule out the possibility that others have used or are using the terminology, but I also can’t rule out the possibility that it’s his own coinage. I definitely would not call it a standard usage.

Comment: Yes, that one. I'm new to topology and this is the first book I ever read about the subject, so I don't know about the use of the terminology. Thanks for the warning @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Eduude: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show every set is saturated, so you can't restrict to $P \in \tau.$ In fact, in what you have shown, is not restricted to $P \in \tau.$

Let $P \subseteq X.$  Then

$$P=X \setminus (X\setminus P)=X\setminus\left( \bigcup_{x \in X\setminus P}\{x\}\right)=\bigcap_{x \in X\setminus P}(X \setminus \{x\}).$$

Since $X$ is $T_1,$ therefore, $P$ is an intersection of open sets and hence saturated. This is essentially what you did but there is no need to first start with $A \in \tau$ or in fact, take $P \in \tau.$